# How to reference a file within build artifact

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I have a release pipeline create from a build pipeline. The artifact that gets created has a PowerShell function - The function deploys a set of resource groups in Azure based around a template.json file. So I need to execute the New-AzDeployment and pass in the template.json from the build artifact.

I've tried using $(Build.SourcesDirectory) and other variables, but the powershell errors as it doesn't know what that is

```
New-AzDeployment -Name "resourceGroupDeployment" `
                 -TemplateParameterFile "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/resourceGroup.Parameters.json" `
                 -TemplateFile "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/resourceGroup.Template.json" `
```

Comment: you likely otta add the error message - all of it - so that someone can make an educated guess about the cause. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch#default-variables) for the default variables that are available in a Release Pipeline.

The one you're looking for is the `$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)` variable. So you'd have something like `"$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)\<artifact_alias>\resourceGroup.Template.json"`.

`<artifact_alias>` is the [Artifact Source Alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/artifacts?view=azure-devops#source-alias) that was set when you added the artifact to your Release Pipeline.